# Minted / xkeyval packages version issue? numberblanklines undefined

Tags: minted, xkeyval, versions

In a completely fresh and updated installation of MikTeX (minted v2.4 and xkeyval v2.7a) I run into a problem using the `numberblanklines` argument. I guess it is version issue because in an older version I do not have this problem/error. The error message is:

```
    Package xkeyval Error: numberblanklines undefined.
```

You can try it using the following MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{minted}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[linenos=true,breaklines,numberblanklines=false]{bash}
    {function h()
    #
    # Type 'h cmd' instead of 'cmd --help'
    #

    {
    echo "--help" | xargs $1
    }
    \end{minted}
    \end{document}
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: this is reported and fixed at source, so you can get an update from github or wait for a ctan update https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much David :-)

Because links might get broken I post the solution that is working as of now (until the new minted version is released):

1. Download `minted.sty` from [here](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/tree/master/source)
2. Put `minted.sty` in your project/the folder where your document is
3. Compile and be pleased that it works :-)